# Eclipse indexing with nRF52 SDK12 (unresolved inclusions)

Tags: eclipse, gcc, sdk

This is a pretty specific problem, but since Nordic's devzone is more or less desert, and this is more of an Eclipse problem, I'm trying.

I'm trying to set a new environment with the SDK12 for the nRF52.
Basically, what I want is a workspace with the SDK12 at its root, and subfolders with the projects I'm currently working on, linked to the SDK resources (as it should be, right?)

It looks like this:

```
/workspace
     ./nRFSDK12
     ./Project1
           ./main.c
           ./someheader.h
           ./Makefile
           ./linker.ld
     ./Project2
           ./...
...
```

Pretty straight forward isn't it?
Question is, **how do I get Eclipse to index those symbols?** `make` works perfectly, but Eclipse is just blind to my inclusions outside the Project1 folder. Directories in Makefile are set as follows:

```
SDK_ROOT := D:/eclipse/cpp-mars/workspace/nRFSDK12
PROJ_DIR := D:/eclipse/cpp-mars/workspace/Project1
TEMPLATE_PATH := $(SDK_ROOT)/components/toolchain/gcc
```

And it doesn't yield any error on `make` commands.

I had followed the Tutorial for SDK11 and did likewise for the automatic discovery of symbols:

> Enter project properties -> C/C++->Preprocessor Include Paths,etc.->Providers
>   Click on CDT GCC Build Output Parser and change the compiler command pattern from (gcc)|([gc]++)|(clang) to (.*gcc)|(.*[gc]++) then apply changes.
>   Click on CDT Built-in Compiler Settings Cross ARM and replace ${COMMAND} with arm-none-eabi-gcc and click Apply.

How do I get Eclipse to include those symbols? If I move the SDK to the Project1 folder, it manages to automatically detect them, but doing so would give me as many SDK copies as the number of projects I'm working on.

[Link to Nordic's tutorial on Eclipse and GCC](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/tutorials/7/)

Answer (score 0):

The "CDT GCC Build Output Parser" will pick up the symbols after a build. My NRF52 projects are setup the same way and it works.

Comment: Yeah well... I'm just confused now. Something is missing.

Comment: Can you tell me where is your PROJECT_LOC path variable in Eclipse, please? Under Properties>Resource>Linked Resources

Comment: In my case output parser is not able parse defines it handles includes somehow.